# Speeding up Pythogrean triple calculator

Tags: java

So far my code runs fine, but I need a way to speed it up. When the user enters max_values to be 25000 it takes about 1.81 seconds and I need it to be less than one second. I tried my best to optimize my triples method but I don't know what else to do.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pythagorean {

public static void triples(int max_values){
    int x = 0;
    for(int c = 5; c <= max_values; c++){
        int cTwo = c * c;
        int b = c - 1;
        for (int a = 0;a <= cTwo - b*b;a++){
            if (a*a + b*b == cTwo){
                x++;
                System.out.println(x + ") " + a + " " + b + " " +c);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("--- Pythagorean Triple Generator ---");
    System.out.println();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int max_value = 0;
    System.out.print("Enter max value for c: ");
    try{
        max_value = input.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
        input.nextLine();
        System.err.println("Error: Input is not an integer.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    input.close();
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    triples(max_value);
    double elapsed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)/ 1000.0;
    System.out.println("Searching complete...");
    System.out.printf("Elpased time: %.3f\n", elapsed);
}
}
```

Comment: Writing to the console is slow. If you don't need that in the loop, skip it. If then you still need better performance, move to C.

Comment: Did you do some research in order to find a library which is faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just ran in 0.999 seconds on my PC.

It uses a single `StringBuilder` to collect all the output, then does just one `println` at the end.

```
public static void triples(final int max_values)
{
    int x = 0;
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(24000);
    for (int c = 5; c <= max_values; c++)
    {
        final int cTwo = c * c;
        final int b = c - 1;
        final int bTwo = b * b;
        final int cTwoLessB = cTwo - bTwo;

        for (int a = 0; a <= cTwoLessB; a++)
        {
            if (a * a + bTwo == cTwo)
            {
                x++;
                sb.append(x);
                sb.append(") ");
                sb.append(a);
                sb.append(" ");
                sb.append(b);
                sb.append(" ");
                sb.append(c);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Yep  thanks works much faster now. I would upvote but I need 15 rep for that so sorry.

Comment: @user1775500 You can select this as your answer and that'll be worth more than an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The bottleneck is most likely `System.out.println`. Writing to the console often takes time.

```
 for (int a = 0;a <= cTwo - b*b;a++){
            if (a*a + b*b == cTwo){
                x++;
                System.out.println(x + ") " + a + " " + b + " " +c);//Do you really need this?
            }
        }
```

Maybe you could store it in a collection and do the printing after the loop is done (or use Stringbuilder as suggested).

Some optimizations:

```
int multiplyB = b*b ;//multiplication can also be slow. 
for (int a = 0;a <= cTwo - multiplyB;a++){
            if (a*a + multiplyB == cTwo){
                ++x;//use preincrement operator
              str.append(x ).append(") ").append(a).append( " ").append(b).append(" ").append(c).append("\n");

            }
 }
```

Comment: Yes it does. It can help to speed it up.

Comment: Yea, I do need that or how else would I get it to print out? Although it is a good suggestion, if printing wasn't needed

Comment: Maybe you could store it in a collection and do the printing after the loop. Or you could use threads, not sure if that would make any big difference..

Comment: +1 it highlights the part that (probably) needs optimising. It doesn't need to completely solve the question to be a useful answer. You could concatenate the strings using a StringBuilder rather than doing a `println` on every iteration.

Comment: @DNA It doesn't provide any solution, and ignores the fact that the OP likely is required to print the solutions to console.

Comment: I am not that experienced of a java programmer, so I have no idea what threads or collections are. I am just looking for a way to optimize my formula,I do not know much about string concatenating so those tips aren't really useful to be. Sorry

Comment: + 1 On my system it takes 2.1 seconds with the println, 0.98 seconds without it.  I don't see any way to get below 1 sec without removing the println every pass.